# Got a way to put those codes together?

Tags: javascript

I am setting up a project in which, cleanly speaking, the user sends an image (upload), it is immediately displayed on the screen and its predominant color is displayed in a specific div.

I already have the code ready and working, but it's separate; One code/script takes care of sending and displaying the image and the other detects the color, but of an image that is already inserted in the document. I can not find a logic that brings them together to make it work as I said at the beginning ...

It is possible?

Here's the online demo:
http://simulaplayer.esy.es/demo/

Here's the view-source:

```
<head>
  <script src="js/color-thief.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
#mydiv {
   width: 100px;

   height: 100px;

   border: 1px solid #000;
}
#clock{
   background-image:url('');
   background-size:cover;
   background-position: center;
   height: 250px; width: 250px;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

/* Image upload and preview: */

<input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" /><br/><br/>
<div id='clock'></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('getval').addEventListener('change', readURL, true);
function readURL(){
   var file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend = function(){
      document.getElementById('clock').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";        
   }
   if(file){
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
    }
}
</script>

/* Picks the main color of the image */

    <img src="img/photo3.jpg" id="myimg" />
    <div id="mydiv"></div>

    <script>
      $(window).ready(function(){
        var sourceImage = document.getElementById("myimg");
        var colorThief = new ColorThief();
        var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
        document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + color + ")";
       });
    </script>
</body>
```

*(Sorry my english, I do not know very well.)

Comment: `Picks the main color of the image` - you run this code once, when the document first loads ... you need to run that code when **after** the image has been read (in readURL)

Comment: @JaromandaX, Can you explain how I do this? My knowledge is still very limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert base64 dataURL to a image before get the main color of the image.see  https://jsfiddle.net/feexon/w1dty7yj please.and you never called get the main color of the image after the image file changed.

```
var image=new Image();
image.src=reader.result
imageChanged(image);
```

Comment: THANK YOU A LOT!! it is perfect :)